# Can the adverb nunc be used in apposition?

Tags: word-order, adverb, word-usage

For a textbook exercise, I translated this sentence from English into Latin.

> The terrified Callisto, now a wild animal, avoided men and beasts
>   (animals).
>
> *(Latin via Ovid)*

Here's my translation.

> Territa Callisto, nunc animal ferum, viros et animalia fera evitavit.

I'm afraid this is a silly beginner's question, but I was wondering, is it correct to use *nunc* in apposition this way? Or would it be better to omit *nunc* and let it be implied?

Comment: My intuition is that the verb _fio_ (to become) is needed anyway. In that case, _nunc_ could even be omitted. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: *nunc cum/quoniam* is used much like English to mean "now that...", but in this case I definitely want to add a *facta*. It's a great question though

Comment: The origin is Ovid  Met. II.ca.495, mens antiqua tamen facta quoque mansit in ursa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### *Nunc* almost always modifies a verb.

I haven't found any instances yet where *nunc* modifies a noun to mean "now being...". For that meaning, you could use a relative clause or put in an *esse* for *nunc* to modify.

From Cicero's *Epistulae ad Familiārēs* 10.31.6:

> ...constitui, **ut nunc est**, cum exercitu proficisci.

(Trans.)

> ...I have decided, **with the way things are now**, to set out with my army.

And from his *Dē Ōrātore* 1.187:

> Omnia fere, **quae sunt conclusa nunc artibus**, dispersa et dissipata quondam fuerunt...

(Trans.)

> Pretty much all the things **which are now incorporated into the arts** had previously been separate and disconnected...

There are some cases when *nunc* modifies a noun. For example, *nunc [noun] nunc [noun]* is an idiom when you give only a few examples from a longer list. "The Helvetii swept through Gaul, destroying the forces of the other tribes: now the Sequani, now the Aedui." But I don't think this is your intent.

Comment: Nunc is never anything but an adverb, with only adverbial uses. In your example "nunc (noun), nunc (noun)", it is still an adverb, used with ellipsis of an actual verb, i.e. one which is necessary to the meaning but is understood.

Comment: @TomCotton I wasn't sure about that, because I didn't find any examples with elided verb except in that particular construction. My English analogy from the answer is not good here: the Latin examples I found did include an actual verb with the *nunc X nunc Y* as its subject or object.